# Convert timestamp to (d.m.Y) in laravel view

Tags: laravel, date, view, timestamp

I found this but it doesnt work :O

Is the syntax wrong?

```
<div class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>{{ $news2->datum ->format('d.m.Y') }}</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: There is a space after `datum`.

Comment: Please give us the full error message. "doesnt work" is not enough for us to understand.

Comment: Call to a member function format() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\j4ylara\resources\views\user\start.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
{{  date("d.m.Y", strtotime($news2->datum)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work since its `$datum` its not a carbon instance.

To make this work go to the news model and declare the date columns so laravel will mutate them to carbon instances on load:

```
 protected $dates = ['datum'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($news2->datum)->format('d.m.Y') }}
```